# Wpf Listview bound object does not have changes

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have listview with textbox in one column. Listview is bound to IEnumerable collection.
When I edit text in textboxes and click OK, bound collection has only original values.
I Snooped listview and see changes made in textboxes appear in listviewitem's objects while listview is on screen, but in OK button handler they all gone.

Here is window's xaml and code-behind (payee is result of linq-to-xml query produced by window's caller):

```
<Grid>  
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,38,0,0" Name="lvPayee" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="lvPayee_Click" Background="AliceBlue">  
        <ListView.View>  
            <GridView>  
                <GridView.Columns>  
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Listed" Width="60">  
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
                            <DataTemplate>  
                                <CheckBox Margin="15,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Listed}"/>  
                            </DataTemplate>  
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
                    </GridViewColumn>  
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Payee" Width="425">  
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TextBox}">  
                                <TextBox Width="420" Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Transparent"/>  
                            </DataTemplate>   
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
                    </GridViewColumn>  
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Use Count" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UseCount}"/>  
                </GridView.Columns>  
            </GridView>  
        </ListView.View>  
    </ListView>  
    <CheckBox Content="Listed Only" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,12,0,0" Name="cbListedOnly" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" IsChecked="True" Click="Listed_Clicked" />  
    <Button Content="OK" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,6,0,0" Name="btnOK" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" Click="OK_Clicked" />  
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="493,6,0,0" Name="btnCancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" IsCancel="True" />  
</Grid>  


public partial class PayeeManager : Window
{
    private IEnumerable<Payee> payees = null;
    private IEnumerable<Payee> payto = null;
    private bool reverse = false;
    private string lastColumn = "";

    public PayeeManager(Window owner, IEnumerable<Payee> payees)
    {
        this.Owner = owner;
        this.payees = payees;
        InitializeComponent();

        payto = from p in this.payees
                        where p.Listed == true
                        orderby p.Name
                        select p;

        lvPayee.ItemsSource = payto;
    }

    public class Payee 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int UseCount { get; set; }
        public bool Listed { get; set; }

        public string OldName { get; set; }
        public bool OldListed { get; set; }
    }

    private void Listed_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        payto = from p in this.payees
                        where cbListedOnly.IsChecked == true ? p.Listed == true : true
                        select p;

        lvPayee.ItemsSource = payto;
    }

    private void lvPayee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.OriginalSource is GridViewColumnHeader)) return;

        string header = (string)((GridViewColumnHeader)e.OriginalSource).Column.Header;
        if (lastColumn != header)
        {
            lastColumn = header;
            reverse = false;
        }
        else reverse = !reverse;

        switch (header)
        {
            case "Listed":
                    payto = from p in this.payees
                                    where cbListedOnly.IsChecked == true ? p.Listed == true : 1 == 1
                                    orderby p.Listed
                                    select p;
                break;
            case "Payee":
                    payto = from p in this.payees
                                    where cbListedOnly.IsChecked == true ? p.Listed == true : 1 == 1
                                    orderby p.Name
                                    select p;
                break;
            case "Use Count":
                    payto = from p in this.payees
                                    where cbListedOnly.IsChecked == true ? p.Listed == true : 1 == 1
                                    orderby p.UseCount
                                    select p;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        if (reverse) payto = payto.Reverse();
        lvPayee.ItemsSource = payto;
    }

    private void OK_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `where !cbListedOnly.IsChecked || p.Listed`

Comment: Not relevant to the problem at hand. The question is how to get changes out of this window to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I used as listview's ItemSource Linq query, and it was refreshed when accessed, loosing changes. I changed ItemSource to List, using ToList() on query and it works now.